# How best can I determine the target rate for a KPI metric?

Tags: statistics, data

I am working on a project where I evaluate the  Key Performance Index (KPI) for a solar company. The aim to see how the company is performing generally and see if it is efficient. Some of the metrics that I look at are:

1. How many solar installation appointments were made weekly?
2. How may dispatch were made based on the appointments?
3. How many appointments were carried over in the week?
4. What is the completion rate for the solar installation?
5. What is the same day rate completion for the solar installation?

For each of these metrics, an arbitrary target rate was set to measure performance. For example, a target rate of 80% was set for item #1, 90% for item #2, 60% for item #3 etc...Anything below these percentages means poor performance for each of the metrics. Please not that these target rates were not based on data or science. I have now been tasked to come up with a target rate that is backed by data and statistics and not one from a manager just throwing out some numbers.

How best can I approach this? How can I provide a better framework on targets setting? What is the cost benefits of setting these targets?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend looking up industry standard for your region/Country, as different geographical locations should have considerable difference due to various factors.
Try to identify those factors and those industry standard values.
If you can get some publically available dataset that pertains to the above conditions, that will be perfect. But TBH finding such a dataset would be tough, if not impossible.

Maybe reach out to industry experts via forums, best would be statisticians working in the solar industry.